# Flutter : Provider gets a null value

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create set a post to firestore using a provider, however, using breakpoints, I see that the providers value remains null, even after giving it a value. I have this code working in another code, but in here I fail to figure out why the providers value remains null.

Code in question from lib/widgets/create_page.dart

```
void addHabit(BuildContext ctx) {

      final habit = Habit(
        title: title.text,
      );

      final provider = Provider.of<TodosProvider>(ctx, listen: false);

      provider.addHabit(habit);

      Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
    }
```

And the provider from lib/providers/habits.dart

```
class TodosProvider extends ChangeNotifier {

  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

   inputData() async{
    final User user = auth.currentUser;
    String uid = '123'; // FOR TESTING PURPOSE
    print('UID TEST');
    print(uid);
    return uid;
  }
  List<Habit> _habits = [];


  void setTodos(List<Habit> habits) =>
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        _habits = habits;
        notifyListeners();
      });

  void addHabit(Habit habit) async => FirebaseApi(uid:await inputData()).createHabit(habit);
}
```

[image]

Posting the github link as well, just in case
https://github.com/sevenfold4/testing1

Comment: Did you get a null exception at  `provider.addHabit(habit);`?

Comment: yes, Added a picture in edit

Comment: that's weird. In your main.dart, try disabling lazy initialization `ChangeNotifierProvider(lazy: false, create: (context) => TodosProvider(),),` and see if that persist..

Comment: provider still null

Comment: I'm not sure if this will fix it, but try to pass the `context` form the `build` method to the provider function instead of the `context` from Builder (rename one of them to be able to choose)..

Comment: You mean, like this Widget build(BuildContext ctx)
and then addHabit(ctx)?
This doesnt change anything, provider still null
I actually tried it at start without specifically sending a context, but same result

Comment: Isn't that Flutter Web where you're debugging? Quite often I notices that VSCode debugger was not reliable and either didn't show proper values or messed with breakpoints/tracing - had to use Chrome DevTools.

Comment: I am using Android Studio

Comment: Did you get a exception like `the method addHabit was call on null`? and btw change the method name hence you are calling provider addHabit method from addHabit method and this sometimes gives unexpected results.

Comment: have you registered your provider? In your code I do not see anywhere it is registered - then it must be null!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the Firebase Instance we are using
When we are creating `TodosProvider` it throws an error stating:
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following FirebaseException was thrown while handling a gesture:
[core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()

we need to `initializeApp` before use so I have created [pull request](https://github.com/sevenfold4/testing1/pull/1) for your reference.
Also after this, there are few errors but it's related to the creation of data and not this issue, so I'm ignoring that, as I've not properly set up the database on my firebase.

Make sure to call before creating myApp class

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
Firebase.initializeApp();
```

Comment: this is so stupid, i went through the code 20 times, but i forgot to init firebase. Thank you!

Comment: anytime brother anytime.

Comment: Since the new update with null safety, i have the problem again. Would it be possible to message you somewhere? Last time your post helped a lot? Nothing has been changed about the providers, only the null safety and dart migration

Comment: I'm sorry I was not following stackoverflow for a while you can connect me on twitter: the_parth_dave